# JAXB objects initialized with default values

Tags: jaxb, xsd, default-value

**There is little problem with JAXB.**

---

**Given:**

- Java 1.5; jaxb -jars from jaxws-2_0.
- .xsd scheme and generated JAXB classes.
- Every simple element in .xsd has default value. And as result class members has annotations like 
  "**@XmlElement(name = "cl_fname", required = true, defaultValue = "[*_*__*_*__]")**"

---

**Required**

---

Get java object (root element) which fully represent xml and every member initialized by default values.

---

when I try to marshall xml without explicitly setting values, default values doesn't make sence... is there any way to marshall xml populated with default values without customization of generated classes?

*example of .xsd:*

```xml
<xs:element name="document">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="d_int"/>
            <xs:element ref="d_double"/>
            <xs:element ref="d_string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="d_int" type="xs:int" default="-1"/>
<xs:element name="d_double" type="xs:double" default="-1.0"/>
<xs:element name="d_string" type="xs:string" default="false"/>
```

*and java class:*

```java
public class Document {
    @XmlElement(name = "d_int", defaultValue = "-1")
    protected int dInt;
    @XmlElement(name = "d_double", defaultValue = "-1.0")
    protected double dDouble;
    @XmlElement(name = "d_string", required = true, defaultValue = "Default")
    protected String dString;
...
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

default value that is in annotations works only after *unmarshalling*.
unmarshal this

```
<document>
   <d_int/>
   <d_double/>
   <d_string/>
</document>
```

and you will get object with default values (-1, -1.0, "Default")

If you want set default values to marshalling, you should do this

```
public class Document {
    @XmlElement(name = "d_int", defaultValue = "-1")
    protected int dInt = 100;
    @XmlElement(name = "d_double", defaultValue = "-1.0")
    protected double dDouble = -100;
    @XmlElement(name = "d_string", required = true, defaultValue = "Default")
    protected String dString = "def";
...
}
```

jaxb generate default values only for unmarshalling

Comment: I've been wondering, is there any point in marking a field as `required` if you also specify a `defaultValue`. That seems to contradict, doesn't it ?

Comment: If you leave off the `defaultValue`, will the value assigned to the field be the default both for unmarshalling and marshalling, or will there be no default value for unmarshalling? (e.g. if you took off `defaultValue = "-1"` for `dInt`, would `100` be the default value for unmarshalling also?)

Answer (score 1):

For an initialization of the class members from XSD supplied defaults, you can use the default-value-plugin of XJC.

See the [website of the plugin](https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Default-Value).

Note that the ant task definition as explained in that documentation did not work for me. [As explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977479/com-sun-tools-xjc-plugin-provider-plugin-not-a-subtype), the class paths for XJC and the plugin have to be separated. Specifying the path to the plugin when calling it works for me:

```
<xjc schema="some.xsd" >
    <arg value="-Xdefault-value"/>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="lib/xjc-plugins/jaxb2-default-value-1.1.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</xjc>
```