# JAXB default value for null elements when marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

At the time of **marshalling** of JAXB object I want to set some defult value to the resulting XML.

I do not want to use `nillable=true` as it generates empty tag with unnecessary `xsi:nil="true"`, and this is not for setting default value. Instead I want to generate the XML with some placeholder characters such as '?'.

Use case :  I am going to build a tool for WebService testing. There I need to present the entire request xml to the user (Like SOAPUI).

Comment: Check if this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040826/jaxb-objects-initialized-with-default-values

Comment: this is only for unmarshalling.

Comment: Why don't you set this values in the JAXB object prior to marshalling?

Comment: Then I would have to write large and complex reflection based code. Just assume that that is almost not possible in my case. I was trying to leverage JAXB for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use case : I am going to build a tool for WebService testing. There I
>   need to present the entire request xml to the user (Like SOAPUI).

The idea of the place holder character isn't really going to work.  For example `?` is an ok default value for a string, but not an int, boolean, or for most complex values (i.e. representing the nested address information for a customer).  Instead you will want a value that reflects the type.

> Then I would have to write large and complex reflection based code. Just assume that 
>   that is almost not possible in my case.

This reflection code probably won't be as bad as you are imagining.  A quick search will probably also reveal libraries that populate objects with "dummy" data.  When hooking it up with JAXB you could leverage a `Marshaller.Listener` to populate the object on the before marshal event.

Comment: Thanks, ultimately implemented using reflection. A recursive method to initialize entire object graph.