# How to use jaxb plugin extensions with gradle-jaxb-plugin

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb, jaxb2-basics

I use gradle-jaxb-plugin to generate classes from an XSD:
https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin

It works fine with external binding and I can use the built-in
XJC extensions without a problem. But I did not manage jaxb
extension plugins to work, in particular -Xinheritance from
the jaxb2-basics.

When I try the configuration proposed in the gradle-jaxb-plugin
documentation, I get the following error:

```
:pwa-application:xjc FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':pwa-application:xjc'.
> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin: Provider org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.jaxbindex.JaxbIndexPlugin not a subtype
```

I have found the explanation in this thread:
[com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin: Provider <plugin> not a subtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977479/com-sun-tools-xjc-plugin-provider-plugin-not-a-subtype)
but there is no solution for gradle-jaxb-plugin there, I got stuck.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I can now answer my question by myself.

The solution is simply to use

```
taskClassname      = "org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task"
```

It is mentioned in the documentation, but there is no explanation.
Now I know what it is for.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please? We are kind of stuck with similar issue.

Comment: Use XJC2Task instead of the default XJCTask: `jaxb { xsdDir = "some/folder"  xjc { taskClassname  = "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task" } }`

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same error.
Project was using Java 11, but `JAVA_HOME` pointed to Java 8.

**After I changed path in `JAVA_HOME` env. variable to Java 11, the issue was fixed**.

Just for inforation - we are using Gradle and working XJC definition for Java 11 for us is following:

```
project.ant {
    taskdef name: "xjc",
            classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
            classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
    mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
    mkdir(dir: classesDir)

    xjc(destdir: sourcesDir) {
        schema(dir: "src/main/resources/xsd", includes: "*.xsd", excludes: "XSD_FILENAME.xsd")
        arg(value: "-wsdl")
        arg(value: "-extension")
        arg(value: "-Xinheritance")
        arg(value: "-Xannotate")
        produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
        binding(dir: "src/main/resources/xsd", includes: "bindings.xjb")
    }
}
```